# Ubuntu Server, multiple simultaneous remote users

Tags: 16.04, server, remote-desktop, remote-x-session

I'm setting up a new Ubuntu Server (16.04) to which up to 50  people will have access at the same time. 
I've followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYe0zo59iT0) tutorial to setup the XRDP with the xfce and every thing is fine so far, the problem is that only 10 users can be logged in at the same time. 
can anyone help  about that.
thank you.

Comment: What happens when another user tries to log in? Is it really a Ubuntu **Server** (without GUI)?

Comment: no there is a GUI (thats why i setup the Xfce) , when 10 users login the eleventh login failes.

Comment: Add 'MaxSessions 50' to the '/etc/ssh/ssh_config' file that should fix it

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Please sorry the change should have been in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` NOT  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. My apologies!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured out the solution, I've increased the MaxSessions in the /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini file.

thank you [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george) your answer served as a great clue.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you managed to setup ubuntu server to host 50 users or so from scratch, pls?!

Answer (score 7):

You need to need to increase the default allowed connection using the

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

File, add the lines

```
MaxSessions 50
MaxStartups 50:30:100
```

to that file.  Then restart you system.

Form man sshd_config(5):

```
MaxSessions
         Specifies the maximum number of open shell, login or subsystem
         (e.g. sftp) sessions permitted per network connection.  Multiple
         sessions may be established by clients that support connection
         multiplexing.  Setting MaxSessions to 1 will effectively disable
         session multiplexing, whereas setting it to 0 will prevent all
         shell, login and subsystem sessions while still permitting for-
         warding.  The default is 10.

 MaxStartups
         Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated con-
         nections to the SSH daemon.  Additional connections will be
         dropped until authentication succeeds or the LoginGraceTime
         expires for a connection.  The default is 10:30:100.

         Alternatively, random early drop can be enabled by specifying the
         three colon separated values ``start:rate:full'' (e.g.
         "10:30:60").  sshd(8) will refuse connection attempts with a
         probability of ``rate/100'' (30%) if there are currently
         ``start'' (10) unauthenticated connections.  The probability
         increases linearly and all connection attempts are refused if the
         number of unauthenticated connections reaches ``full'' (60).
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't solve it.

Comment: @Melebius, thanks was accessing from my mobile at the time :).

Comment: I've figured out the solution, I've increased the MaxSessions in the /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini file.

thank you @George your answer served as a great clue.

Comment: @S.Ghanim you should [accept his answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) instead of posting "thanks" as a separate answer.

Comment: @muru it is not the answer to my question, however I thanked him for the clue he gave, so whats wrong with this!!!!!!

Comment: @S.Ghanim ah, I didn't notice you edited a different file.